# Allow multiple values return in Function and add some missing text C#

Tags: c#

```
static double masodmegold(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double x0, x1, x2;
    double gyokalatt = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (a == 0)
    {
        //i want to write some text out here
        return double.NaN;
     }
     else
     {
         if (gyokalatt > 0)
         {
             return x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
             return x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
             // i cant return two values
         }
         else if (gyokalatt == 0)
         {
             return x0 = (-b / (2 * a));
         }
         else
         {
             return double.NaN; 
             // also some text here
         }
     }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(masodmegold(1, 4, 3));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I am trying to write some function for the quadratic equation. Its working, but not totally correctly. I cant return two values, i tried the 'Tuple' but it wont work, so i need some suggestions. Also, i cant return some text just a NaN...

Comment: Can you specify what doesn't work about the Tuple?

Comment: Instead of trying to return NaN + text, you could throw an exception.

Comment: if you realy wanted to return some text, why not returnning an Object

Comment: @FaLiar what are the values you'r trying to return?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
static double[] masodmegold(double a, double b, double c)
{
    if (a == 0)
    {
       return new double[0];
    }

    double gyokalatt = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (gyokalatt > 0)
    {
       double x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
       double x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
       return new double[] { x1, x2 };
    }
    else if (gyokalatt == 0)
    {
       double x0 = (-b / (2 * a));
       return new double[] { x0 };
    }
    else
    {
       return new double[0];
    }
}
```

You can do the "writing out" in the code which calls your method.  It can get the array back, check its length, and then write out a message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return two values, but it's possible to rewrite your method to use `out` parameters, like so:

```
static double masodmegold(double a, double b, double c, out double x0, out double x1, out double x2) {
    // no need to declare the x0, x1, x2 variables
    double gyokalatt = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (a == 0)
    {
        //i want to write some text out here
        return double.NaN;
    }
    else
    {
        if (gyokalatt > 0)
        {

            x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
            return;
        }
        else if (gyokalatt == 0)
        {
            x0 = (-b / (2 * a));
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            return double.NaN; 
            // also some text here
        }
    } 
}
```

and then read the values of x0, x1 and x2 after your method call.

Comment: he could also declare a public variable and change it value in the method... then read it's value later

Comment: @Slashy that's not a good idea as it's not portable and some other method could also change it's value

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the flow of the application to suit your need, like printing directly from `masodmegold` :

```
static void masodmegold(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double x0, x1, x2;
    double gyokalatt = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (a == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i want to write some text out here");
        Console.WriteLine("double.NaN");
    }
    else
    {
        if (gyokalatt > 0)
        {
            // i cant return two values
            // while you can't reutnr twice, you can just print them out directly
            Console.WriteLine((-b + Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a));
            Console.WriteLine((-b - Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a));
        }
        else if (gyokalatt == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(-b / (2 * a));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("i also want some text here");
            Console.WriteLine("double.NaN");
        }
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    masodmegold(1, 4, 3);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Alternatively, you can also create a new class for the return type.

```
class MasodmegoldResult
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public double Value1 { get; set; }
    public double Value2 { get; set; }

    public static MasodmegoldResult Error(string message)
    {
        return new MasodmegoldResult()
        {
            ErrorMessage = message,
            Value1 = double.NaN,
            Value2 = double.NaN,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `yield return`

```
static IEnumerable<double> masodmegold(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double x0, x1, x2;
    double gyokalatt = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (a == 0)
    {
        //i want to write some text out here
        return IEnumerable.Empty; 
    }
    else
    {
        if (gyokalatt > 0)
        {

            yield return x1 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
            yield return x2 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(gyokalatt)) / (2 * a);
            // i cant return two values
        }
        else if (gyokalatt == 0)
        {
            yield return x0 = (-b / (2 * a));
        }
        else
        {
            return IEnumerable.Empty; 
            // also some text here
        }
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(string value in masodmegold(1, 4, 3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```